# select only and element on a list of xpaths

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome, xpath

`$x("//div[@class='card-info__container']/div[3]/a")`
using this I've found the container, but now I can't get the specific element I need.

when I enter this the response is:

```
⯆(3) [a.cta.btn, a.cta.btn, a.cta.btn]
  ⯈0: a.cta.btn
  ⯈1: a.cta.btn
  ⯈2: a.cta.btn
```

how can I take only the first one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thanks for pointing that out and if you want can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I really don't know how to help here, I'm sorry

Comment: is it because the question is asked poorly or you don't know how to do it? so I can edit the question

Comment: At least from my side I see I just don't know that. Generally I have some knowledge about xpath but here I can't help. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) method to select the first item from the array of `a` that is returned from executing the XPath:

```
$x("//div[@class='card-info__container']/div[3]/a").at(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

For an XPath that returns a list of elements,

```
xpath
```

you can select only the first element via indexing:

```
(xpath)[1]
```